# Black Navigation Bar covering image view in collection view header

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, imageview

I have a collection view header who's background contains an image. What I am trying to do is allow for the image to be the background of the navigation controller.

> What I have now 
> [image: Current]

> This is what I am trying to achieve
> [image: What i am trying to achieve]

I have tried a lot of things so far. I made the navigation bar translucent. I adjusted the edges for extended layout, and I have set the property of navigation controller to be under opaque bars.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.lightWetAsphalt
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
    collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.never
}
```

Note: If i hide the navigation controller, the image view goes under the status bar perfectly fine. For some reason, when I don't hide the navigation bar, thats when it brings up this black view

Comment: try this: `hideNavigationBarDuringPresentation`